# Push TabBar Scene from another Scene : react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to push a `TabBarScene` from a navigator like this -

```
 this.props.navigator.push({title:'',component:MainTabBarPage,titleTextColor:'#FFFFFF',barTintColor:'#FF4600',tintColor:'#FFFFFF'});
```

or also by a `this.props.navigator.replace` method with same props
But I get this error -

> Exception: If waiting for observedTopOfStack to reach
>   requestedTopOfStack, the only valid observedTopOfStack should be
>   requestedTopOfStack.

Where exactly am I going wrong. I'm not getting the answer for this anywhere.